# Printf in errors.New possible?

Tags: go

I've grown fond of the `Printf` of `fmt` and `log`

Is there a way I can use it with `errors.New`?

I tried the following:

`return errors.New(fmt.Printf("User %v already exists", dbcfg.Username))`

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Errorf

Comment: return fmt.Errorf("User %v already exists", dbcfg.Username)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `fmt.Sprintf` to format things into a string and `fmt.Errorf` to format into `error`.

Comment: This is great thank you. return fmt.Errorf("User %v already exists", dbcfg.Username)